# Unity3d ai stucking other object

Tags: unity-game-engine

i'm new on Unity3d and i'm trying to writing simple ai. But i have some problem. AI stucking other object. And here is my code. Thank you.

[code1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5uc7R.png)

[code2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ftln5.png)

Comment: Please do not post code as images.

Comment: Please add more information regarding the problem. The AI object is always stuck or it get stuck in specific situations? Objects can collide with the ground, so if you are not filtering the collisions that might be the problem. If that's not the case I need more information to understand the problem.

Comment: My problem is, when player stay behind the objects. and ai try to walk. and its stuck. if you want any specific information, please just write what you want.